# Who would speak like this: I loves me a good Brick Joke or Chekhov's Gun

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, slang

I think I've heard [I loves me ...] on TV. But I do not have any memory of it. A Google search would throw some results. One of which is:

> I loves me a good Brick Joke or Chekhov's Gun

Another is:

> I loves puns

So other than a non-native speaker or a child still learning the language who would speak *I loves* or any other verb for that matter. Is it rural/regional/humorous/etc?

Comment: "I loves me a [object]" is a very slightly humorous reference to a Southern U.S. dialectical usage. It is probably more used by non-speakers of that dialect than by its actual speakers. The form is usually _Subjective Pronoun +loves +Objective Pronoun +some +[object]._ You might also hear "They loves them some biscuits!" or "We loves us some hog jowls." _Love_ is the usual verb thus abused. A variant is _I just gotta have me some [object]._

Answer (score 2):

***I loves me a [object]*** is a very slightly humorous reference to a Southern U.S. dialectical usage. It is probably more used by non-speakers of that dialect than by its actual speakers. The form is usually

> *[Subjective Pronou] +loves +[Objective Pronoun] +some +[Object].*

Thus you might also hear (or, more rarely, see written) *They loves them some biscuits!* or *We loves us some hog jowls.* **Love** is the usual verb thus abused, although **need** is occasionally seen.

A variant is *I just gotta have me some [object].*